# Centering of \paragraph and \bibliography headings in memoir class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir

I am currently working on a thesis. The office of graduate studies demands the following style changes:

*All* headings centered

I am using the memoir package. I was able to center Chapter, Sections, Subsections and subsubsections using

```
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\chaptitlefont\centering}
\setsecheadstyle{\bfseries\Large\centering}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\large\centering}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\centering}
```

I have to, but was not able to center the headings of:

Paragraphs

TOC

List of figure

List of tables

Biblography (natbib package)

List of abbriviations (acronym package)

List of symbols (nomencl package)

What can I do? Thanks! Philipp

Comment: Please post **complete** code. That is much more useful than a fragment since it is much easier to reproduce the issue you are seeing and to test solutions. All questions should include a Minimal Working Example. That is, not your entire thesis (!) but a small sample of code people can compile to show the specific issue you are asking about.

Comment: With all those problems, maybe you should try another document class.

Comment: My problem can be solved as described below by @karlkoeller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With these lines in the preamble, all the headings you've mentioned will be centered (apart from `paragraph` which doesn't behave as a title)

```
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\centering\chapnumfont \thechapter}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\Huge\bfseries\centering}
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\centering}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\centering}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\bfseries\centering}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\centering\chapnumfont \thechapter}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\Huge\bfseries\centering}
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\centering}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\centering}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\bfseries\centering}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{A chapter}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

If you really want `\paragraph` to behave as other sectioning commands, also add these lines in the preamble:

```
\setparaheadstyle{\normalsize\bfseries\centering}
\setbeforeparaskip{-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}
\setafterparaskip{1.5ex plus .2ex}
```

Comment: @Philipp Thanks for accepting. Happy to have helped you.